# how can i get name from javascript to code behind from following

Tags: javascript

this is the method to get userinfo from gmail. i dont know how to pass username values to code behind can any one help ..

```
function getUserInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken/acToken,
        data: null,
        success: function (resp) {
            user = resp;
            console.log(user);
            $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
            $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });
}
```

Comment: "i dont know how to pass username values to code behind"? What that supposed to mean?

Comment: `data: "{'name':'John'}",` should be `data: {'name':'John'},`

Comment: What do you mean by "code behind". You want to pass the response to the back-end (PHP, Java)? Or you want to use in you JavaScript code?

Comment: i am using asp.net c# as code behind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the response you got from ajax call in the code behind. For that you have to set the value to a hidden field. So that you can access the values in code behind using its ID.

You can use this code if you are working with ASP .net

```
 HTML code -- 
  <asp:hiddenfield ID="user" runat="server"></asp:hiddenfield>

 Jquery
  $("#user").val(user);    // Add data to html field

 CodeBehind

 Object user = user.Value;
```

Comment: Edited  my previous post. Please check